# xcode delete a column for a sql database

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to delete a column from an SQLlite database. I have Googled this and it seems to be impossible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete or add column in SQLITE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442147/how-to-delete-or-add-column-in-sqlite)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete column from SQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938048/delete-column-from-sql-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`ALTER TABLE` manual](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html);

> SQLite supports a limited subset of ALTER TABLE. The ALTER TABLE command in SQLite allows the user to rename a table or to add a new column to an existing table. **It is not possible to rename a column, remove a column, or add or remove constraints from a table.**

So, no, not without dropping and recreating the table.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html):

> It is not possible to rename a column, remove a column, or add or
>   remove constraints from a table.

I guess it has to be done manually.