# Change Column name and type SQLITE

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I have already create the huge database in my application. Now, I have to update one column with name and size with programatically.

**As per my research:
 - Add new column in table
 - Drop older column from table**

I add new column but how to delete old column from table.

Can anybody help me ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to the is a pure SQL command. Take a look at:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp

Comment: Drop Column query is not working on sqlite.

Comment: Sorry! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938048/delete-column-from-sql-table

Comment: By the way, I use SQLite Manager as an add on to Thunderbird and it does a good job. Maybe worth looking at.

Comment: I have to go with your link steps to save data. Anyways its work for me. Thanks :)