# How clean text in search view when click outside

Tags: android, menu, searchview

I have a search view in my app. Also have menu search. How do I clean text from search view when I clik outside (for example somewhere on empty place)? I was looking for an answer to the question, but I didn't find appropriate.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.searchable_dictionary, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchableInfo info = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(info); 




        return true;


    }




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search:
                onSearchRequested();
                return false;

            case R.id.about:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
                return true;


            default:
                return false;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite has limited ALTER TABLE support that you can use to add a column to the end of a table or to change the name of a table. If you want to make more complex changes in the structure of a table, you will have to recreate the table. You can save existing data to a temporary table, drop the old table, create the new table, then copy the data back in from the temporary table.

For example, suppose you have a table named "t1" with columns names "a", "b", and "c" and that you want to delete column "c" from this table. The following steps illustrate how this could be done:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1_backup(a,b);
INSERT INTO t1_backup SELECT a,b FROM t1;
DROP TABLE t1;
CREATE TABLE t1(a,b);
INSERT INTO t1 SELECT a,b FROM t1_backup;
DROP TABLE t1_backup;
COMMIT;
```

[How to delete or add column in SQLITE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442147/how-to-delete-or-add-column-in-sqlite)

[Delete column from SQLite table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938048/delete-column-from-sql-table/5987838#5987838)

**EDIT**

this is the solution for your problem said in comment:

here,

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmployeeDetails.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        startActivity(intent);
```

the problem is with your intent.!! you are passing **this** as the context, but here the **this** not referring to your Activity.. it is the onClick! your logcat may give you a NPE or illegal as exception, 
change to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(EmployeeList.this , EmployeeDetails.class);
```

Comment: Tnx bachu for answer. I am beginer, so found simpler solution. I created new project with new database:) When I start app it works, but when click on item appears unffortunatly stoped :/

Comment: post the logcat, probably bcz of the contxt.. and modified my ans by guess.. please check it

Comment: I am grateful to you for your answers bachu. I posed logCat beyond.

Comment: App running, but when I click on item it says unffortunatly stoped. My adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter is coated, and painted in yelow :/ My logCat and explanation of the problem is beyond (answer 2).