# Rails 4 DB Migration Error: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration, rails-migrations

I am relatively new to rails and in the process of coding an application. So far the app itself works great. Lately I wanted to migrate something like this: **(Updated)**

```
class ChangeStuffFromTools < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :tools, :shares, :integer, :default => 0
    change_column :tools, :views, :integer, :default => 0
    change_column :tools, :likes, :integer, :default => 0
    change_column :tools, :favorites, :integer, :default => 0
    change_column :tools, :featured, :boolean, :default => false
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
$ rails g migration remove_stuff_from_tools
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20160904090608_remove_stuff_from_tools.rb

Jonas@JONAS_PC ~/gitapps/ocubit (master)
$ rake db:migrate
== 20160904090608 RemoveStuffFromTools: migrating =============================
-- remove_column(:tools, :featured, :boolean)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
c:/Users/Jonas/gitapps/ocubit/db/migrate/20160904090608_remove_stuff_from_tools.rb:3:in
change'
      c:inmigrate' NoMethodError: undefined method to_sym' for nil:NilClass
      c:/Users/Jonas/gitapps/ocubit/db/migrate/20160904090608_remove_stuff_from_tools.rb:3:in
  change' c:in `migrate' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How can I possibly fix it, I mean I somehow need access to my database to edit it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for [remove_column](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/remove_column) is:

```
remove_column table_name, feild name
```

So try:

```
class RemoveStuffFromTools < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :tools, :featured
    remove_column :tools, :shares
    remove_column :tools, :views
    remove_column :tools, :likes
    remove_column :tools, :favorites
  end
end
```

#### Update:

For sqlite `remove_column` isn't supported, for simple development db you could:

1. Update your original `create_table_migration` and remove unwanted columns.
2. Recreate your db: `rake db:drop` then `rake db:create` and finally `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Hmm, that's what I tried before - the same error pops up. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @J.Hübotter are you using sqlite? re-check column names spelling

Comment: yes, nothing changed from the default, the columns are spelled correctly

Comment: i don't think sqlite support `remove_column` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442147/how-to-delete-or-add-column-in-sqlite . there are some hacky ways http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938048/delete-column-from-sqlite-table/5987838#5987838 but should drop and recreate if it's in devlopment

Comment: Is there an easier way to just update these columns?

Comment: you can edit your migrations and remove unwanted columns from the `create_table_migration` then do `rake db:drop` then `rake db:create` and finally `rake db:migrate`

Comment: You are a genius! Didn't thought about that solution. Feel free to update your post, I'll mark this as answered then :)

Comment: One should back up data say into a CSV file or generate insert statements to bring it back because rake db:drop will remove all the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the column's default value or null value, you can use the following methods, too:

```
change_column_default(:accounts, :authorized, 1)
change_column_null(:users, :nickname, false)
```

For more info, [here are more migration methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html)