# How to delete specific table's column using FMDB?

Tags: ios, swift, fmdb

I am trying to delete column last_name from Persons using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb),

```
let query = "ALTER TABLE Persons DROP COLUMN last_name;"
try FMDBHelper.database.executeUpdate(query, values: nil)
```

But comes with error

> DB Error: 1 "near "DROP": syntax error".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete or add column in SQLITE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442147/how-to-delete-or-add-column-in-sqlite)

Comment: @AhmadF FYI i am trying in SWIFT-FMDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlite does not support DROP COLUMN in ALTER TABLE.

You can only rename tables and add columns.

If you need to remove columns, create a new table, copy the data there, drop the old table and rename the table to its intented name.

Reference: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Answer (score 0):

*Please note that I flagged that your question could be duplicated, I will provide an answer to make it more clear.*

I think that you are *missing* a point, which is: The [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) is (as mentioned in their repo description):

> This is an Objective-C wrapper around ***SQLite***

Keep in mind that since FMDB is built on top of SQLite, it is *not* a limitation from the library itself; it is related to how [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) `ALTER TABLE` works.

The [SQLite `ALTER TABLE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) statement is limited to *rename* a table and `add` a new column to the desired table:

> SQLite supports a **limited** subset of ALTER TABLE. The ALTER TABLE
>   command in SQLite allows the user to rename a table or to add a new
>   column to an existing table.

<sub>http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html</sub>

---

**For achieving what are you looking for:**

You could check the answers of [Delete column from SQLite table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938048/delete-column-from-sqlite-table/5987838#5987838).