# Removing column gives syntax error

Tags: sql

I'm using SQLPro for Mac.

I have a table called `mc_question` which has a column called `name`

I've run the following query:

`ALTER TABLE mc_question
DROP COLUMN name;`

But I get the error: `near "DROP": syntax error (Line 2)`

Comment: Which database is the query being executed against? The syntax depends on the DB.

Comment: It's apparently an SQLite database. A google search tells me it doesn't support drop column :\

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938048/delete-column-from-sqlite-table/5987838#5987838