# Slow writing on SQLite database after ALTER

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a relatively big SQLite database (~900 MB) with 3 tables inside. I recently removed a field from the main table, through the software SQLlitebrowser. I used the answer found here: [Delete column from SQLite table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938048/delete-column-from-sqlite-table/5987838#5987838)

And I basically ran this:

`BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1_backup(id, percentage_match, doi, title, date, journal, authors, abstract, graphical_abstract, liked, url, new, topic_simple, author_simple);
INSERT INTO t1_backup SELECT id, percentage_match, doi, title, date, journal, authors, abstract, graphical_abstract, liked, url, new, topic_simple, author_simple FROM papers;
DROP TABLE papers;
CREATE TABLE papers(id, percentage_match, doi, title, date, journal, authors, abstract, graphical_abstract, liked, url, new, topic_simple, author_simple);
INSERT INTO papers SELECT id, percentage_match, doi, title, date, journal, authors, abstract, graphical_abstract, liked, url, new, topic_simple, author_simple FROM t1_backup;
DROP TABLE t1_backup;
COMMIT;`

I also tried to run that query through a python script.

After the alteration of the database, writing into the main table is extremely slow.
When I try to write on the original database (I made a backup before removing the field), I can write into the main table more or less 10000 times faster.

Do you have an idea about why this is happening ? I tried to vacuum the newly altered database, but the loss of performance is still here.

EDIT:

@neuhaus: I ran .schema (first time I hear about it, forgive me if I misused it) on the new table:

`sqlite> .schema papers
CREATE TABLE papers(id, percentage_match, doi, title, date, journal, authors, abstract, graphical_abstract, liked, url, new, topic_simple, author_simple);`

And on the old table:

`` sqlite> .schema papers
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "papers" (
    `id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `percentage_match`  REAL,
    `doi`   TEXT,
    `title` TEXT,
    `date`  TEXT,
    `journal`   TEXT,
    `authors`   TEXT,
    `abstract`  TEXT,
    `graphical_abstract`    TEXT,
    `liked` INTEGER,
    `url`   TEXT,
    `new`   INTEGER,
    `topic_simple`  TEXT,
    `author_simple` TEXT
, url_image TEXT); ``

It's obvious there is a difference. It seems the types of the fields are not present in the new table. What do you think, and how do I correct that ? ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the schema of the old table and the new table using the `sqlite3` utility and its `.schema` command.

The new table is likely to be missing an index.

Use the CREATE TABLE statement given to you by the output of the `.schema` command (without the column you want to drop) instead of the one you are using now.

Comment: I edited my question to add the results of ```schema```

Comment: I edited my answer. Just change the create table statement and add the primary key. You probably also want to add the AUTOINCREMENT that was in the old table.

Comment: Should I also add the type for the other fields ?

Comment: yes, unless you want to change the type for some reason (which I consider unlikely)