# Sqlite Dropping Column from table

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

Why sqlite database has the limitation of "not to drop a column from a table"
in a single command?
Are there any chances it would be added in future versions?

Answer (score 4):

`ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN` is now supported, as of 3.35.0 which was released 2021-03-12.

Comment: Are you talking about the SQLite version 3.35.0 or is it android version and is there any provision for this in Android Room DB?

Comment: I'm talking about SQLite version 3.35.0. I don't know if Room supports it.

Answer (score 1):

> SQLite supports a limited subset of ALTER TABLE. The ALTER TABLE
>   command in SQLite allows the user to rename a table or to add a new
>   column to an existing table. It is not possible to rename a column,
>   remove a column, or add or remove constraints from a table.

https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

No, you can't.

> Are there any chances it would be added in future versions?

Well, we can't tell you that. And even if they will add it, there are still a lot of Android devices out there which have an older version of SQLite without that feature.

However, you can delete a column like this from this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5987838/5457878

Answer (score 0):

The ALTER TABLE statement supports exactly those operations that can be implemented easily without having to rewrite the entire table. (When adding a new column, that value is missing in all rows; it gets replaced with the column's default value when read.)

The ability to drop columns (or other things, like reordering columns) would add lots of complex code to the SQLite library.
However, SQLite is designed as an embedded database, so it must take care to conserve resources. It is very unlikely that such a large amount of code will ever be added.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q11

> SQLite has limited ALTER TABLE support that you can use to add a column to the end of a table or to change the name of a table. If you want to make more complex changes in the structure of a table, you will have to recreate the table. You can save existing data to a temporary table, drop the old table, create the new table, then copy the data back in from the temporary table.

So you can't just delete the column