# How do I delete column from table in room database?

Tags: android, android-room

How do I delete column from  table in room database android.I alredy try all the way drop and delete not working.

This code also not working:-

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_3_4 = new Migration(3, 4) 

{
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) 
{

 database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE users_new (userid TEXT, username TEXT, last_update INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(userid))");

// Copy the data

 database.execSQL("INSERT INTO users_new (userid, username, last_update) SELECT userid, username, last_update FROM users");

// Remove the old table
 database.execSQL("DROP TABLE users");

// Change the table name to the correct one

 database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users_new RENAME TO users");

    }
};
```

Comment: can you please add your code, even if it is not working?

Comment: database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users DROP COLUMN  users_id");

Comment: Can you please format your code?

Comment: so you are migrating from a starting version, which has a column that the new version does not have, right? how do you know those SQL commands are not working?

Comment: When I am runinng code it give error in this code database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users DROP COLUMN users_id");  and the code i mention with queation is also not working .And you right about so you are migrating from a starting version, which has a column that the new version does not have, right.

Answer (score 1):

Android ROOM is based on SQL Lite which does not allow dropping database table columns. Instead you have to:

- create a temporary table without the column you are trying to delete,
- copy all records from old table to new table,
- drop the old table,
- rename new table to same name as old table

See related question:[Sqlite Dropping Column from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46938787/sqlite-dropping-column-from-table)