# Android Room migrations did not properly handled

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have written Android Room migrations, but somehow it does not handle it properly.

Here is the error:

```
    Expected:
TableInfo{name='Likes', columns={creatorId=Column{name='creatorId', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, messageId=Column{name='messageId', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, createdAt=Column{name='createdAt', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, dbId=Column{name='dbId', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, timestamp=Column{name='timestamp', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
 Found:
TableInfo{name='Likes', columns={dbId=Column{name='dbId', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, creatorId=Column{name='creatorId', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, messageId=Column{name='messageId', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, timestamp=Column{name='timestamp', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

Here is migration script:

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Likes (id TEXT, creatorId TEXT, messageId TEXT,"
                       + " timestamp TEXT, dbId INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(dbId))");
```

Here is model class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "Likes")
public class LikeDbModel {

@PrimaryKey private int dbId;
private String id;
private String creatorId;
private String messageId;
private String timestamp;
private String createdAt;

public LikeDbModel() {
}
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to add the column createdAt.
When you create your database add the line .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2) to the creation of the database, which I think you have done.

```
INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        YourDatabase.class, "your_database.db")
                        .addMigrations(
                                MIGRATION_1_2
                        )
                        .build();
```

Then implement the migration properly by first dropping the table and then creating it or using an alter table statement.

```
    static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
           //Either
           db.execSQL("drop table Likes"); //if existing table
           db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Likes (id TEXT, creatorId TEXT, messageId TEXT,"
                   + " timestamp TEXT, createdAt TEXT, dbId INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(dbId))")

            //or
            db.execSQL("alter table add createdAt TEXT");

    }
};
```

The error you are getting is because room is comparing your entity to the existing table in the database.  You could also wrap the migration statements in a try/catch SQLiteException to see what is working.

If you don't want to lose the data in your table, use an alter table instead.  If you want to drop/create, the make sure you copy the data over to a new table first with the new structure, copy the data to the new table, drop your original Likes table and rename you new table to Likes.  See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938048/delete-column-from-sqlite-table/5987838#5987838)

Room documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions

Answer (score -1):

Its missing the createdAt field in the migration